# What does the Frequent tab mean?

Tags: support, question-lists, linked-questions

The description for the frequent tab is,

> Questions with the most links

What does this mean? What's the link that the statement refers to?

[image]

Comment: Frequently asked questions get closed as duplicates of other questions. The more duplicates a question has closed against it, the more frequently asked it is.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Click through to any of the questions in that list, and look on the right-hand side bar under the "linked" header - those are all the questions with links to or from the question you're viewing.

The questions with the most links *to* them are displayed in the Frequent tab.

Those links might be in other questions, in answers, comments, or in the duplicate header added when a question is closed as a duplicate.

Essentially, these are the most-*referenced* questions.