# Is there a way to search the top-viewed posts for an entire site?

Tags: support, sorting

By just browsing through Stack Overflow and viewing posts with a high number of views and/or votes, I have found basic programming concepts and problems that others have run into, which have inadvertently helped me quite a lot in my own work.

Some of these problems would have created bugs or problems with my code if I did not know them before I went live, but by hitting the questions/answers with the largest number of views for a specific subject or programming language, I was able to avoid the major bugs that others have run into around the world (as evidenced by the number of views and votes that the question has gotten over the years). This was not intentionally done; I just happened to be curious and interested in other posts with a large number of views and, what do you know!, it gave me a better way to code something, or a better configuration that I otherwise would not even know to look for.

Because SO is now such a resource for programmers, new and experienced alike, it seems that it would be a useful feature to be able to view all questions for a particular tag sorted by number of views and number of votes.

Perhaps the “Frequency” tab could be used for this, but I can't tell exactly how it is sorting the questions for a particular tag.

Also, I'm honestly curious what the most viewed post on the site is, and I don't know how to find out. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Votes (use the "Filter" button to apply filters as desired)

Comment: [*curious what the most viewed post on the site is*](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1371854)

Comment: @CodyGray that is votes, not views right? AFAIK there is no Viewcount sort option.

Comment: In my defense, @rene, the question says "a high number of views and/or votes". You expected me to read *all* of the words?

Comment: @CodyGray meh, 50% is a pass from me ....

Comment: MSE related about the views: [How do I sort the questions by the number of views?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27274/how-do-i-sort-the-questions-by-the-number-of-views)

Comment: Also relevant: [What does the Frequent tab mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344306/what-does-the-frequent-tab-mean)

Comment: Now that I think about it... is there a way to view top voted *posts* (as opposed to just questions) natively on the site?

Comment: @zcoop98 A bit hacky: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%2canswer

Comment: @Tomerikoo It's amusing (though I guess somewhat unsurprising) that the first 6 items are Q-A pairs, where the answer belongs to the question listed immediately below it in the ranking.

Comment: @zcoop98 As you said, not necessarily surprising. Those 3 questions have views by the millions. It makes perfect sense that most votes will come in pairs: *"Hey that's exactly the question I looked for.... mmm Great answer too!"* ;)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. Interesting that the top 2 highest voted answers are regarding `git`... At least as of today 11 Feb 21.

Comment: That probably speaks to both git's ubiquity and it's complexity lol. In fact, 4 of the top 10 viewed are tagged with [git]!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*By views*...
As [@rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) alluded to [above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405109/is-there-a-way-to-search-the-top-viewed-posts-for-an-entire-site#comment823720_405109), SEDE (the Stack Exchange Data Explorer for the uninitiated) is going to be your only bet for *true* sorting by views.

As such, [here's a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1366529/top-100-posts-by-view-count) for the Top 100 Posts by Views that I adapted a bit ago.

It’s worth noting that "views" aren't tracked for answers though, since answers are always attached to questions, so there will only be questions in this list.

---

By votes [is easy though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Votes) (via [@CodyGray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray)’s [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405109/is-there-a-way-to-search-the-top-viewed-posts-for-an-entire-site#comment823718_405109)). This feature is built into the site.