# "Home" and "Questions" showing different questions

Tags: support, homepage, question-lists

I'm a new user and am trying to understand the Stack Exchange sites/Stack Overflow.

On the Stack Overflow  main page I've got a menu on the left which shows "Home" and below it "Questions" (among other entries). Both sites show me the new questions.
However "Home" shows some new questions, that don't show up on "Questions".
All filters are disabled, sorting by Newest.

Why is there a difference?

Comment: Generally: The homepage shows a curated selection just for you, while the "questions" page is unfiltered.  Hopefully someone can find more detailed information, though.

Comment: So you missed the big buttons saying "newest" and "active"?

Comment: @RyanM But in my case, "Home" shows all questions from "questions" plus some more that are not shown on "questions". If questions is unfiltered and home a selection, shouldn't "questions" show more than "home"?

Comment: @Tom What do you mean? I have it set on "newest" on the "questions" page. On the "home" page there are other filters like "Intereseting, Hot, Week, ..."

Comment: There should be buttons at the bottom of the Questions page to see more pages.  The [Stack Overflow questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) has over 21.5 million questions that you can get to from it, which is definitely more than the homepage.

Comment: *"What do you mean? I have it set on "newest" on the "questions" page"* ... correct and the homepage is set to "active". So one only shows newest questions, whereas the other shows questions where something happened recently.

Comment: It'll all start to become clear once you start to configure watched and ignored tags. Then the home page starts to do its own thing.

Answer (score 1):

There are three main differences between the two pages: how many questions are shown, which tabs are available, and whether or not you can apply filters.

### Filters

On the questions page, there is a Filter button on the top right, which gives you several options to sort or filter questions. There is no such feature on the home page.

### How many questions are shown

The home page will never show you more than ~100 questions. There isn't any next page, so the only way to see more questions is to go to the questions page.

The questions page has no upper limit on how many questions it can show. If you've applied a filter (either manually or by visiting a tab such as Bountied or Unanswered), it will show you all questions that match the filter, no matter how many there are. If you haven't applied any filter, it will simply show you all the questions that were ever asked on the site (exception: the Frequent tab won't show you *all* questions ever asked on the site, but it will still show hundreds of thousands of questions).

Of course, the questions page won't show you all questions on the same page. On the bottom of the page, you can choose to show 15, 30 or 50 questions per page. If you want to see more questions than that, you can go to the next page.

### Which tabs are available

**Tab present on both pages**

The Bountied tab is present on both pages. The Bountied tabs are identical on both pages, except for filters and how many questions are shown, for which the differences are mentioned above.

**Tabs present on the home page**

- The **Interesting** tab shows questions that the site thinks you might find interesting. Exactly how that tab works is described [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/09/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/):

  > Starting with a list of the last 3,000 active questions:
  >
  > - drop questions containing any of your ignored tags
  > - drop closed questions *if* you lack the reputation required to vote for reopening
  > - drop questions scoring -4 or lower
  >
  > Next, apply the following score formula to the remaining questions:
  >
  > |  |  |
  > | --- | --- |
  > | Your watched tags* | maximum of +1,000 per tag (scaled), up to +2,000 total |
  > | question score | +200 × score, up to +1,000 total |
  > | total answer score | -200 × score, up to -1,000 total |
  > | number of answers | -200 × answers, up to -1,000 total |
  > | number of views | -15 × views, up to -1,000 total |
  > | question last activity date | -1 × (seconds / 15) |
  >
  > *<sub>The original says "interesting tags" because that's what it was called when it was written.</sub>
  >
  > Count it all up and take the top 90 by score.
  >
  > We also mix in a few random questions from the last 3,000 — 10% (9) for logged in users and 20% (18) for anonymous users. We're like **DJs trying to spin a mix of songs** (emphasis in original) — some you might know by heart and love, others you might not have chosen for yourself, but could possibly like if you gave them a fair listen.
- The **Bountied** tab shows a list of questions with an active bounty. This tab is also present on the questions page.
- The **Hot**, **Week** and **Month** tabs show a list of questions with the most views, answers, and votes over the last few days, this week and this month, respectively. [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/349538) explains exactly how the Hot tab works, the Week and Month tabs probably work similarly but allow for slightly older questions.

**Tabs present on the questions page**

- The **Newest** tab shows a list of all questions ever asked on the site, sorted from the newest question to the oldest.
- The **Active** tab shows a list of all questions ever asked on the site, sorted from the most recently active question to the least recently active question. There are a lot of different things that can cause a question to be considered active, a complete of which can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/349538).
- The **Bountied** tab shows a list of questions with an active bounty. This tab is also present on the home page.
- The **Unanswered** tab shows a list of questions with no upvoted or accepted answer. Note that questions with answers can still appear in this tab, as long as the answer is not upvoted or accepted.
- The **Frequent** tab shows a list of the questions sorted by [how many links there are to them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344319/4284627).
- The **Votes** tab shows a list of all questions ever asked on the site, sorted from the question with the highest score to the question with the lowest score.
- The **Unanswered (my tags)** tab works like the Unanswered tab, except it only shows questions tagged with with at least one of your watched tags (regardless of whether or not they're tagged with any of your ignored tags).
- In addition, you can create custom tabs by clicking on Filter, selecting which questions you want to filter and how you want to sort them, and clicking on "Save custom filter".

Comment: For me, the Home page now only shows "Stack Overflow Recently Active Questions". I can't find any tabs on the Home page to "Interesting", "Bountied", "Hot", "Week" and "Month". Is this change due to the [new post summary designs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el), maybe?

Comment: @TheAmplitwist I don't have a sock to test on a non-Team account, but perhaps you're a member of an SO Team?

Comment: That's right, @AndrewT., I am a member of an SO Team.

Comment: @AndrewT. Just to let you know, I am no longer a member of any Teams, and I can now see the "Interesting", "Bountied", and other tabs on the Home page.